# How to get data from localstorage into text field without button in JS

Tags: javascript

Do you think it's possible to retrieve a text from the localStorage and display it immediately without going through a button, like below?

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 id="h1">Hello unknown ! </h1>

    <label>Name: </label>
    <input type="text" id="myName">
    <input type="button" value="ok" onclick="btnStorage()">
</div>
```

---

```
function btnStorage(){
    if(localStorage.getItem("myName") != null)
    h1.textContent = `Hello ${localStorage.getItem("myName")}`;
    
    localStorage.setItem("myName", myName.value)
}
```

Comment: Call `btnStorage()` after the DOM has loaded. One option is to use the window's `DOMContentLoaded` event, `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', btnStorage);`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event

Answer (score 1):

Old but gold.

```
<body onload="btnStorage()"></body>
```

Comment: could describe why you are posting the code and what it would fix? :)

Comment: you can run a function you want to run after the page loads